# Multiple if statement until Column has the data and need result in New Column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am a beginner in VBA trying to write the code for `If` that would help me in my daily task, however, I am getting an error. Please review and help me. Also I want it to run till the Column AD is blank.

I have just written it in Excel

```
IF(AD2<=0,"Negative", 
  IF(AD2<67,"$1 - $67", 
    IF(AD2<100,"$67 - $100", 
      IF(AD2<200,"$100 - $200", 
        IF(AD2<300,"$200 - $300", 
          IF(AD2<500,"$300 -$500", 
            IF(AD2<1000,"$500-$1000",">=1000")))))))
```

I want this results in `Column AE`.

Comment: _"...However, I am getting an error..."_. Care to share this error?

Comment: And I am not entirely sure what this has to do with VBA. Can you add more details?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what error you are getting but seeing your logic, you will get your desired output by re-writing your formula as follows:
<sub>Note: (You can use <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> to enter formula in a cell in the following manner)</sub>

```
=IF(AD2<=0,"Negative", 
IF(AND(AD2>0,AD2<=67),"$1 - $67", 
IF(AND(AD2>67,AD2<=100),"$68 - $100",
IF(AND(AD2>100,AD2<=200),"$101 - $200",
IF(AND(AD2>200,AD2<=300),"$201 - $300",
IF(AND(AD2>300,AD2<=500),"$301 - $500",
IF(AND(AD2>500,AD2<=1000),"$501 - $1000",">$1000")))))))
```

If you want to automate this using VBA as part of your original question, you can try the following.

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim myformula As String

myformula = "=IF(AD2<=0,""Negative"","
myformula = myformula & "IF(AND(AD2>0,AD2<=67),""$1 - $67"","
myformula = myformula & "IF(AND(AD2>67,AD2<=100),""$68 - $100"","
myformula = myformula & "IF(AND(AD2>100,AD2<=200),""$101 - $200"","
myformula = myformula & "IF(AND(AD2>200,AD2<=300),""$201 - $300"","
myformula = myformula & "IF(AND(AD2>300,AD2<=500),""$301 - $500"","
myformula = myformula & "IF(AND(AD2>500,AD2<=1000),""$501 - $1000"","">$1000"")))))))"

With Sheets("Sheet1") '/* change it to your actual sheet name */
    lr = .Range("AD" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("AE2:AE" & lr).Formula = myformula
End With
```

You can actually assign the formula string in one go without using variable.
And also without using concatenation as I did above but just for clarity's sake,
 I divided each portion of the formula to make sure we've covered everything. HTH.